Generate 200MHz Phase-Shifted Voltage Sine Waves
I'm looking into a way to construct a circuit that can generate ~200MHz negative voltage sine waves (8 channels), where there is 11 degrees of phase offset between the channels (0 deg, 11 deg, 22 deg, ...). I would like to be able to adjust the frequency, phase offset and possibly amplitude of the individual sine waves/channels.
After browsing different forums, I wasn't able to find anything for my frequency range of interest (50MHz - 300MHz). Some ideas that came to mind after extensive browsing were to use a voltage-controlled-oscillator (VCO), phase-locked loops (PLL), and variable-gain-amplifiers (VGA). Another idea that I thought of was to first generate the desired sine wave and try to use a tapped-delay-line (TDL) to get the phase shifted sines. However, there didn't seem to be any TDLs with small-enough tap-delay-step (not to mention them having a minimum delay of >2ms), which made me give up on that idea.
Do you happen to have any suggestions or recommendations on how I can design such a circuit? Any help is greatly appreciated!!!
P.S. the voltage range of interest is [0 ; -10V] (10V P-P centered around -5V)

What's your budget? Are you making one, a few, or thousands?

This is going to be very expensive... Are you sure you really need those extreme requirements? The frequency range and output voltage in particular are going to make this difficult. (The latter could be done with eight external amplifiers, for example, which you can buy instead of building.)

To answer the above questions - I am making one for myself, and the maximum budget is ~5k USD. As far as the requirements go - tuning the frequency is essential, for the output voltage - I have a NI9264 DAQ that I was thinking to use together with bias tees to get the negative voltage. In that sense, you may disregard the requirement for [0V ; -10V] and just assume that the sine waves are centered about 0V.

AD9957 on analog.com, or AD9177. I'm not suggesting a specific part, just examples of a class of parts

Thank you! This might really work. I will post an update once a complete circuit has been implemented ;)

Can probably find a PLL eval board that can do this for a few hundred dollars. The ability to adjust per output phase is fairly common on multichannel PLLs running at a few hundred MHz.

I did find some PLL evaluation boards online that even offered much higher frequencies than what I stated (which is good), however, wouldn't a PLL circuit/board also require a low pass filter to create the sine wave, with the cutoff frequency set about roughly 100MHz (for the 50MHz to 300MHz range)?

Wavelength (in air) of 200 MHz is ~1.5m, so 11° corresponds to ~4.5cm, or a bit less in copper. Phase delay could be as simple as fixed lengths of cable, or a slider on an open line for complete variability.

This really is the simplest solution in terms of adding the phase shifts to the signal. I really like the idea of using a slider on an open line to set the correct phase, however, there are no open line sliders to my knowledge. I see slider pots. Perhaps a 5cm 10kOhm slider pot would work. The circuit that I drive with the 200MHz sine wave has an input impedance of several mega ohms. Adding 10k ohm slider pot in series shouldn't cause anything, I presume.
